# Python format with variable digits count

Tags: python, formatting, format, number-formatting

So, I can do:

```
>>> '%.4x' % 0x45f
'045f'
```

But I need to pass 4 from variable, smth like

```
>>> digits=4
>>> '%.'+str(digits)+'x' % 0x45f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` operator has a higher precedence than `+`, so you need to put the first part in parenthesis:

```
>>> digits = 4
>>> ('%.'+str(digits)+'x') % 0x45f
'045f'
>>>
```

Otherwise, `'x' % 0x45f` will be evaluated first.

---

However, the modern approach is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for string formatting operations:

```
>>> digits = 4
>>> "{:0{}x}".format(0x45f, digits)
'045f'
>>>
```